# NHibernate Join Query with only one instance of QueryOver and no mapping relation defined

Tags: c#, join, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my case, I only have a specific repository. Lets say '*StudentRepository*'. This repository hides the *ISession* instance from me and only thing I have is the *IQueryOver< Student,Student>* instance.
Consider below  entities have a simplistic mapping with NHibernate.

```
class Student
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Number  {get;set;}
}

class Exam{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public double Score {get;set;}
    public string StudentNumber {get;set;}
}
```

You are right, the basic way just add the real relation to Exam class like:

> public Student Student {get; set;}

Unfortunately, that is not an option either

The problem: I need to query with some criteria like "Score>70" on Exam entity from studentRepository. How can I produce such a query with Nhibernate without knowing session and no relation defined on mapping. ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378224/nhibernate-queryover-to-join-unrelated-entities/49913474#49913474

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NHibernate QueryOver to join unrelated entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378224/nhibernate-queryover-to-join-unrelated-entities)

Comment: In this example there is no available option to use session directly. the session is unknown here. Only think available is spesific QueryOver<Student,Student> instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main problem here as I see it: to make joins to unrelated entities with QueryOver it's required to have alias defined as variable for root query (your QueryOver for students).
How to do such joins explained in [NHibernate QueryOver to join unrelated entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378224/nhibernate-queryover-to-join-unrelated-entities)

So if you can modify your repository class to allow to provide optional alias variable for this `QueryOver` it would be the best solution. Something like this (I assume you are using NHibernate 5.1 or higher) :

```
Student studentAlias = null;
var studentsQueryOver= yourRepository.GetQueryOver<Student>(studentAlias);

Exam examAlias = null;

var students = studentsQueryOver
.JoinEntityAlias(() => examAlias, () => examAlias.StudentNumber == studentAlias.Number)
.Where(s => examAlias.Score > 70)
.List();
```

If it's not an option you still can create joins to unrelated entities but you need to build them directly with underlying root `Criteria`. Something like this:

```
Exam examAlias = null;

studentsQueryOver.RootCriteria
.CreateEntityAlias(
        nameof(examAlias),
        Restrictions.EqProperty("examAlias.StudentNumber", studentsQueryOver.RootCriteria.Alias + ".Number"),
        JoinType.LeftOuterJoin,
        typeof(Exam).FullName);

var students = studentsQueryOver
.Where(s => examAlias.Score > 70)
.List();
```

And on NHibernate versions before 5.1 you can use subqueries:

```
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Exam>()
    .Where(e => e.Score > 70)
    .Select(e => e.StudentNumber);

subQuery.RootCriteria.Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("StudentNumber", studentsQueryOver.RootCriteria.Alias + ".Number"))

//Or if root query alias variable available simply
//subQuery.And(e => e.StudentNumber == studentAlias.Number)

var students = studentsQueryOver
    .WithSubquery.WhereExists(subQuery)
    .List();
```

Comment: Realy thanks, but I can not figure it  out how can i access 'JoinEntityAlias' method. I couldn't find it.

Comment: It''s available since NHibernate 5.1

Comment: It seems that I am using Nhibernate 4.0.0.0 withal I can not update my nhibernateVersion. And your answer is correct. Thank you.