# NHibernate + QueryOver: How to join unmapped entity by ID?

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, queryover

given is the table A with columns EntityType (Enum that specifies either Entity/Table of type B or Entity/Table of type C) and EntityID (ID of an entry in table B or table C).

Both classes B and C implement interface IBC and class A has a property IBC.

This works, but when I have one A and access property IBC it will do one more query to select the row of either table B or C. If I have a lot of A's it will do a lot of queries.

I want to do this query with NHibernate QueryOver so that there will be no more additional queries:

select * from A a
left join B b on b.ID = a.EntityID
left join C c on c.ID = a.EntityID

Is there any possibility?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NHibernate QueryOver to join unrelated entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378224/nhibernate-queryover-to-join-unrelated-entities)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the latest feature of NH 5.0

[17.5. Join entities without association (Entity joins or ad hoc joins)](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover_entityjoin)

small cite:

> In QueryOver you have the ability to define a join to any entity, not
>   just through a mapped association. To achieve it, use JoinEntityAlias
>   and JoinEntityQueryOver. By example:
>
> ```
> Cat cat = null;
> Cat joinedCat = null;
>
> var uniquelyNamedCats = sess.QueryOver<Cat>(() => cat)
>     .JoinEntityAlias(
>         () => joinedCat,
>         () => cat.Name == joinedCat.Name && cat.Id != joinedCat.Id,
>         JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
>     .Where(() => joinedCat.Id == null)
>     .List();
> ```